# Unix Socket C: Connecting from another network

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp

i'm starting to learn how to configure a unix server/client basilar application in C with tcp socket, now the thing is, I always connect from client to server simply using the port I've choose in the server, and a (local?) address like 192.168.1.X. I honestly don't know anything about it, I presume that 192 is a local interface address and so the connection can only be achieved in the same network, I've tried also with two PCs but still in the same network. What about a connection from another network? It's a complicated thing? I suppose just passing my Network's provider IP to the client won't do the job

Comment: You need to configure port forwarding in your router.

Comment: You can run a web browser on the server's machine and point it to whatismyip.com to find out the IP address that machine is known to the Internet by.  Note that if the server machine is behind a NAT, that IP address will be the address of the NAT instead, and you'll need to configure port forwarding on the NAT in order for incoming TCP connections to that IP address on your chosen port to reach your server machines.

Comment: "*... unix server/client basilar ...* a what please?

Comment: Guys, that is not a programming related quedtion, so it's clearly off-topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network configuration.

Comment: FYI you really shouldn't use the phrase "UNIX socket" unless you mean an *actual* UNIX socket, which is very different from an Internet socket on  a UNIX system.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in such a case you open up a router configuration web page in a browser and in a section "Port forwarding/triggering" enter the entry redirecting connections from outside the LAN to some port on a given machine on LAN, e.g:

```
#   Service Name          Start Port    End Port    Server IP Address
    1   myServerOnPort9875  9875          9875      192.168.1.7
```

Given your external ip is 89.75.140.30 you can now connect from anywhere with

```
telnet 89.75.140.30 9875
```

to reach port 9875 on your local machine 192.168.1.7 assuming the server is listening on 0.0.0.0 for IPv4 and 0::0 for IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have got a static global IP on the server side, just the ip of the server should suffice. However sometimes the network provider uses NAT, which allots you a private IP while all communication is made through the network provider's gateway IP. In such a case the network provider should forward the particular port you want to use to your machine (which probably they wont). Otherwise, your server will will not be able to communicate with clients outside the network of the network provider.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address 192.168.1.x is an address in one of the ranges for private use, typically used in home networks with a WiFi router. You should be able to connect from inside that network (depending on the exact network setup), but not from outside.